# How to load directories from a database into a QTreeView?

Tags: qt

I have a column in my database called "Path" which looks like this:

```
c:\windows\system\
c:\folder2\subfolder\subsubfolder\
c:\folder2\subfolder2\subsubfolder\
c:\folder2\other\
d:\dir
d:\anotherdir
...
```

All those directories are different (Unique) in the table.

I want to load them into a QTreeView and have them displayed like when using a QFileSystemModel. Is this possible? How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. You do need to write some code for that. Qt doesn't include such functionality.

If you wish the model to be modifiable (say, you wish to remove items from the tree), you can implement a `QAbstractItemModel` model that wraps a `QSqlTableModel` or a `QSqlQueryModel` and exposes the data as a tree.

If you only care about static models, you can iterate over your database table and build a tree-shaped `QStandardItemModel`, then view that.

Comment: Thanks, I've started right after publishing the question making my own subclass of QStandardItemModel that internally uses a QSqlQuery object (result from a SELECT directory FROM mytable") and was thinking how to make the String paths into rows of the QStandardItemModel.  But I would probably like to allow the user to remove elements from the tree or maybe even drag them from one dir to another. You say it's not possible by using QStandardItemModel?

Comment: @StephenH.Anderson It is possible, just that you will need to act on the item deletion signals from the model by deleting relevant items from the database table(s).

Comment: Oh, ok, I'm not sure about the differences. First time implementing my own model... Thanks